# Make flex items take content width, not width of parent container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a container `<div>` with `display: flex`. It has a child `<a>`.

How can I make the child appear "inline"?

Specifically, how can I make the child's width determined by its content, and not expand to the width of the parent?

**What I tried:**

I set the child to `display: inline-flex`, but it still took up the full width. I also tried all other display properties, but nothing had an effect.

**Example:**

```css
.container {
  background: red;
  height: 200px;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
}
a {
  display: inline-flex;
  padding: 10px 40px;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="#">Test</a>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/donpinkus/pen/YGRxRY

Answer (score 517, accepted):

Use `align-items: flex-start` on the container, or `align-self: flex-start` on the flex items.

No need for `display: inline-flex`.

---

An initial setting of a flex container is `align-items: stretch`. This means that flex items will expand to cover the full length of the container along the cross axis.

The `align-self` property does the same thing as `align-items`, except that `align-self` applies to *flex items* while `align-items` applies to the *flex container*.

By default, `align-self` inherits the value of `align-items`.

Since your container is `flex-direction: column`, the cross axis is horizontal, and `align-items: stretch` is expanding the child element's width as much as it can. (The `column` setting is also the reason why `display: inline-flex` isn't working.)

You can override the default with `align-items: flex-start` on the container (which is inherited by all flex items) or `align-self: flex-start` on the item (which is confined to the single item).

---

Learn more about flex alignment along the *cross axis* here:

- [How does flex-wrap work with align-self, align-items and align-content?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42613359/3597276)

Learn more about flex alignment along the *main axis* here:

- [In CSS Flexbox, why are there no "justify-items" and "justify-self" properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32551291/3597276)

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation.
Been using flex for a while now, but there are a lot of details that one can easily miss.

Comment: by some reason didn't work here:
https://jsfiddle.net/b8zd37st/

Comment: Thanks for this. What's wrong with using `inline-flex` to prevent the flex box from taking the parent's width?

Comment: @MAZ, didn't work because your flex container is in `row` direction (unlike in the question which is `column`). Hence, the `align-*` properties, which work along the cross axis, move items vertically in your layout, not horizontally. In your case, use `display: inline-flex`. https://jsfiddle.net/uvrja2e3/

Comment: @Crashalot, it won't work because the container is set to `flex-direction: column`. There would be nothing wrong with *"using `inline-flex` to prevent the flex box from taking the parent's width"*, if the container were in `row` direction.

Answer (score 30):

In addition to `align-self` you can also consider auto margin which will do almost the same thing

```css
.container {
  background: red;
  height: 200px;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
}
a {
  margin-right:auto;
  padding: 10px 40px;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="#">Test</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

`width: min-content` also yields the same result.
Not supported in IE11 if that matters to you: https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_width_min-content