# image auto stretches in flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm wondering why any image I put in this div container with display flex is automatically stretched out? And if I were to set a width for it, I can't center it with `justify-content`.

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#container div {
  padding: 25px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#container div h1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#container input,
#container button {
  width: 75%;
}

#container img {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>
    <h1>a</h1>
    <img src="https://placehold.it/350x150">
    <input type="text" name="a">
    <input type="text" name="b">
    <button>a</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nqt8bw4z/ auto stretch 
https://jsfiddle.net/nqt8bw4z/2/ fixed width but doesn't center

Answer (score 1):

An initial setting of a flex container is [**`align-items: stretch`**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40141163/3597276). This means that flex items will expand the full length of the container's [**cross axis**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32551291/3597276). That would be the container's height in `flex-direction: row`, and width in `flex-direction: column`.

Since you're working with a column-direction flex container, the image is stretching horizontally by default. You can override this setting with another value. Try `align-items: flex-start` or `center`.

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#container div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;  /* NEW */
  width: 500px;
  padding: 25px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}

#container div h1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#container input,
#container button {
  width: 75%;
}

#container img {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>
    <h1>
      a
    </h1>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
    <input type="text" name="a" />
    <input type="text" name="b" />
    <button>
      a
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: and the important part is that he cannot align it by using `justify-content: center;` on the image itself [also he cannot make it a flex container]

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer of @Michael_B your code can be simplifed like below as you don't need all these flexbox properties.

```css
#container div {
  padding: 25px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  width: 500px;
  margin:auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items:center;
}

#container input,
#container button {
  width: 75%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>
    <h1>a</h1>
    <img src="https://placehold.it/350x150">
    <input type="text" name="a">
    <input type="text" name="b">
    <button>a</button>
  </div>
</div>
```