# css - flexbox inheriting parent width despite align-items: flex-start, justify-content: flex-start

Tags: css, flexbox

Wanted behavior: I would like the `.container` div to adjust to the width of the `.chapers` div which should adjust to the width of the `.chapter-link` divs. Both the `.container` and `.btn` divs should have the current height of the viewport (`100vh`).

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40141163/make-flex-items-take-content-width-not-width-of-parent-container) I added `justify-content` and `align-items` : `flex-start` to the container, but the problem remains.

```css
.container {
  background-color: blue;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.chapters {
  padding: 14px;
}

.btn {
  background-color: green;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.chapter-link {
  margin-bottom: .5em;
    max-width: 200px; 
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='chapters'>
    <div class='chapter-link'>Test title</div>
    <div class='chapter-link'>Test title</div>
    <div class='chapter-link'>Test title</div>
    <div class='chapter-link'>Test title</div>
  </div>
  <div class='btn'>&lt;</div>
</div>
```

Comment: issue with `width` or `height` ?

Comment: `width`, height works as expected.

Comment: in this case you need `inline-flex`... the alignment affect the cross axis not the main axis

Comment: thanks, that solved the problem. Feel free to write it us as an answer and I'll accept it.