# How can I get flexboxes to take up the minimum amount of space without forcing contents to wrap?

Tags: css, flexbox

Instead of expanding to fill available space, I want the flexboxes to allow all my content to fit without getting any bigger. For example, in [this photo](https://i.imgur.com/2rhvoFv)
you can see that Insurgency:Sandstorm is forced to wrap. Obviously, I could manually adjust it to look good on (my) desktop browser, but I'd like it to dynamically resize itself if someone opens it on mobile.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/mpx/pen/OegvmV)

```
.panel {
    display: flex;
    margin: auto;
    width: 52%;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    background-color: #282936;
    border: 1px solid #191921;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
```

Comment: allow wrapping and do not `.panel-content {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 justify-content: space-around;
 /*justify-content: flex-start;*/
 align-items: center;
 color: #8A8DB7;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
.panel-content h3 {
 font-size: 1.75em;
 white-space:nowrap;
 padding: 15px;
}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make flex items take content width, not width of parent container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40141163/make-flex-items-take-content-width-not-width-of-parent-container)

Comment: add `align-items: flex-start` to the panel. It has already been answered on this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40141163/make-flex-items-take-content-width-not-width-of-parent-container

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe I'm misunderstanding, but [this is the result](http://prntscr.com/oambce). I don't want to hard-code width. @AdrianDanlos Should I enclosing all the panels in a flex box, or something?