# Flex div (do not stretch full width)

Tags: css, flexbox

I have 2 divs and using flex:

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background: red;
}

.item {
  height: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

<div class="parent">
  <div class="item">something here</div>
</div>
```

My issue is that the parent is 100% the width of the screen.

How can I make it so it stay's as large as the item content, so auto grows (when there's more text is grows or shrinks with less)?

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40141163/make-flex-items-take-content-width-not-width-of-parent-container/40141200

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use inline-flex instead of flex:

```
display: inline-flex;
```