# Unexpected behavior with inline-block

Tags: html, css

Someone here recommend me to use `display:inline-block` to make the width of the element be the same as its content. So I tried, but doing so, I ended up with the text getting all mixed. How do I fix this?

The second pair is what I wanted, but with the width of the Paragraph extending only as its content.

```html
<p style="display: inline-block">Inline-block P</p><span>Normal span</span>
<p>Normal P</p><span>Normal span</span>
```

Comment: `The second pair is what I wanted` so ? you have what you wanted .. and why you want the width to extend content and also a line break ? simply keep the default behavior

Comment: keep the inline tag and add a ``<br>`` tag where yo want the text to break

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your title say **Unexpected behavior** but this is the normal behavior. You made your element to behave like an inline element so there is no more line break and thus you will have this behavior.

If you want the `p` to have only the width of its content AND to have line break simply wrap it inside a div (a block element):

```html
<div>
  <p style="display: inline-block;background:red;">Inline-block P</p>
</div>
<span>Normal span</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've set your elements to `inline-block`, which makes them inline-level, which places them on the same line.

Here's an alternative: Use an inline-level flex container, like this:

```css
body {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

body > * {
  border: 1px dashed red;
}
```

```html
<p>Inline-block P</p>
<span>Normal span</span>
<p>Normal P</p>
<span>Normal span</span>
```

More info: [Make flex container take width of content, not width 100%](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42686681/3597276)

---

Or use a block-level flex container, but override the default `stretch` value on `align-items`:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

body > * {
  border: 1px dashed red;
}
```

```html
<p>Inline-block P</p>
<span>Normal span</span>
<p>Normal P</p>
<span>Normal span</span>
```

More info: [Make flex items take content width, not width of parent container](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40141163/3597276)

Comment: i also though about flex but the only issue is that it will break the behavior of spans that come next to each other [but not sure if the OP want this or not]

Comment: @TemaniAfif, between your answer and mine, one of them should be useful to  him :-)

Comment: yes sure, but i was simply curious if we can change behavior of only the p element but i guess not as all the child will be flex items and will behave the same ...

Comment: @TemaniAfif, without more details from the OP we can't be more precise.

Answer (score -1):

Make your span display = block.

HTML:

```
<div id=container>
   <p>Hello, world!</p><span>Here is my span</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
   margin: 5px;
   padding: 5px;
}
div {
   background: gray;
}
p {
   background:white;
   border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
   display: inline-block;
}
span {
  display: block;
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HuFZL/774/).